# Does anyone know how should i put in coding when i perform a certain action(ex. entering a trigger) when im using the new player input system?

Tags: unity

```
void OnMove(InputValue value)
{
    moveInput = value.Get<Vector2>();
}    

void OnDash(InputValue value)
{
    if(value.isPressed)
    {
        if(!isDashing)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Dash());
        }
    }
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.tag == "Protect")
    {
        Debug.Log("Traced");
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))   <---- this is what I would do on the old input
        {
            //Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your old input system code would only work if the player pressed the button in the exact instant that they touched the trigger, so that's probably not the behaviour you want to replicate. Can you edit this to show a more practical example of what you want? (Also, remember to always use `.CompareTag()` instead of `.tag == `)

Comment: Best guess: Rising a shild or something like that to defend against an attack. You could set a bool as long as you perform the action and check in the Trigger if the bool is true